# Responsive FileManager Upload Window Too Small

Tags: fancybox, responsive-filemanager

I am using Responsive FileManager 9.10.1 (although this problem existed from previous 9.x.x versions as well): when the folder I'm browsing has just one line of files (e.g. if it's empty), and then I click upload, the RFM window doesn't grow larger, making it a very uncomfortable upload.

Is there some config option to enlarge the window? Is this a real RFM issue or is it just me?

[image: Visual representation of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to get around this is the "hacky" way: the class for the viewing area in RFM is called `fancybox-inner`. If its `min-width` is set to 580px, the upload iframe will fit perfectly inside.

This doesn't solve the problem of uploading a whole lot of files in a way that the upload window's height becomes higher, however, for most practical purposes it works.